# Retrieve List of data from Firebase database Android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have product child in my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO75V.png), and I need to retrieve all its children as a list so I can view it in my app in list view.
how can I do it?

thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read through the [documentation on work with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those products, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = rootRef.child("products");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String product = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", product);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
aa
appledd
bb
fruitrtyyty
//an so on
```

Comment: thank you,
but can I access the children attributes?

Comment: Yes you can, goind deeper in your database tree.

Comment: I tried to do this:
                    String productID = ds.getKey();
                    String pName = productsRef.child(productID).child("name").toString();

but the app crashed, is it wrong?

Sorry i'm new in firebase

Comment: No, this isn't the right way of retriving those childrens but this is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.